# Cocos2d-x 3.2 getFileDataFromZip failed

Tags: android, zip, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, android-external-storage

I use obb extensions in my android project for resources
All path is currectly `(/storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/path to file),` but  `file = unzOpen(zipFilePath.c_str());` always return null!

what's can be wrong?

```
P.S.:zipFilePath - currectly too
```

Comment: are you pre-pending `getWritablePath()` to your `zipFilePath.c_str()`?

Comment: All is okey. I just not currectly archiving, i archive with WINRAR, but should ZIP